# send click count to django view using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to send click id of item to Django view on every click so that I can update count against every item.
I achieved this by using ajax and javscript but there is some issue when id is sending id to Django view.

what actually happening-

when I click on any item(1)(first time) - nothing happen

but when I click on any item(let suppose 2) - then it send 1 and 2

again when I click on item 3 - it send 1,2,3

I don't know why it is behaving like this.

it should send only one item it which is clicked

my code is-

```
{% for solution in item %}
        <ul>

            <li >{{solution.solution_name}}
                <a href="#"><i  value="{{solution.id}}" class="fa fa-download down" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="count(document.getElementById('fname_{{solution.id}}').value)">
               <input type="text" id="fname_{{solution.id}}" value="{{solution.id}}"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
```

my ajax part-

```
    <script>
        function count(a) {
    var id = parseInt(a);
    $('.down').click(function(e){
        console.log("clicked item id is")
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(id);


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/solutions/count',
        data: {
          'id': id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            alert("A user with this username already exists.");
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your function on click and in that function you got another click event, this will create you problems, so you need only one click event

use:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.down').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('value');    

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/solutions/count',
        data: {
          'id': id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            alert("A user with this username already exists.");
          }
        }
      });
    })

});
```

Remove the onclick attribute form your html